# Throwing error Cannot POST /api/password-reset in postman

Tags: node.js, express, postman

Im trying to send mail when user clicks on forgot password to reset the email.But im getting this error. for other post requests like /users, /auth its working fine. But for password-reset post request its giving CANNOT POST error in postman.
index.js file

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import userRoutes from "./routers/users.js";
import authRoutes from "./routers/auth.js";
import resetPasswordRoutes from "./routers/passwordReset.js";

const app = express();

// middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

// routes
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("api/password-reset", resetPasswordRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const URL = process.env.URL;

console.log(process.env.BASE_URL);

//connect to mongodb atlas
mongoose
    .connect(URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Connected to mongoDB Atlas successfully");
        app.listen(PORT, () =>
            console.log("Server is listening on the port " + PORT)
        );
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

router/passwordReset.js

```
import express from "express";
import { passwordReset } from "../controllers/passwordReset.js";
import { passwordResetRequest } from "../controllers/passwordReset.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", passwordReset);
router.post("/:userId/:token", passwordResetRequest);

export default router;
```

controllers/passwordReset.js

```
import User from "../models/user.js";
import Token from "../models/token.js";
import sendMail from "../utils/sendEmail.js";
import Joi from "joi";
import crypto from "crypto";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

export const passwordReset = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
        const schema = Joi.object({
            email: Joi.string().email().required(),
        });
        const { error } = schema.validate(req.body);
        console.log(req.body);
        if (error) return res.status(400).send({message: error.details[0].message});

        const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
        if (!user)
            return res.status(400).send({message: "user with given email doesn't exist"});

        let token = await Token.findOne({ userId: user._id });
        if (!token) {
            token = await new Token({
                userId: user._id,
                token: crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex"),
            }).save();
        }

        const link = `${process.env.BASE_URL}/password-reset/${user._id}/${token.token}`;
        await sendMail(user.email, "password reset", link);

        res.send({message:"password reset link has sent to your email account."});
    } catch (err) {
        res.send({message:"An error occurred"});
        console.log(err);
    }
};

export const passwordResetRequest = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const schema = Joi.object({ password: Joi.string().required() });
        const { error } = schema.validate(req.body);
        if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

        const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId);
        if (!user) return res.status(400).send("Invalid link or expired");

        const token = await Token.findOne({
            userId: user._id,
            token: req.params.token,
        });

        if (!token) return res.status(400).send("Invalid link or expire");

        user.password = req.body.password;
        await user.save();
        await token.delete();

        res.send("password reset successfull");
    } catch (err) {
        res.send("An error occured");
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

postman request sending url - http://localhost:5000/api/password-reset
ERROR in postman - Cannot POST /api/password-reset, 404Not Found
Anyone help me with this error

Comment: Typo: `app.use("/api/password-reset", resetPasswordRoutes);` (the slash before `api` was missing).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a typo in your route string. '/' missing.

`app.use("api/password-reset", resetPasswordRoutes);`

Should be

`app.use("/api/password-reset", resetPasswordRoutes);`